# Want to add Account wrapper

Tags: magento-1.9, php, header

### What is location of Account tab ?

I want to add the "account" tab in the header section.

Where is the template of that "account" tab is located in the base package/rwd package ?

Comment: Please check i have added answer hope it's work for you.

Comment: this question is not clear please provide screenshot and more detail

Answer (score 0):

Add "My Account" link goto `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/page/html/header.phtml.` In this file you can add your custom 'li' tag and can put a link for "My Account" as Controller moves it to My Account PAGE.

One more way here for you :

Open theme/layout/customer.xml file and then modify the section that shows customer links on all pages, to include a link home and also a link to other customer service pages that you have deemed necessary, e.g. ‘returns’ (if you get a lot of those enquiries...).

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Home</label><url></url><title>Home</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>5</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>94</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Deliveries</label><url>deliveries</url><title>Deliveries</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>95</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Returns</label><url>returns</url><title>Returns</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>96</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>97</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Second method is standard let me use that